# Python package can't import neighbor subpackage when called from outside

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I created a simple package to illustrate this problem. Here's the file structure:

```
pypkg
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── sub_a
│   └── __init__.py
└── sub_b
    └── __init__.py
```

`sub_a` has a function `foo`:

```
# sub_a/__init__.py
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

`sub_b` has a function `foobar` that calls `foo`:

```
# sub_b/__init__.py
from sub_a import foo

def foobar():
    foo()
    print 'bar'
```

In the main file, I import `foobar` without issues:

```
# __main__.py
from sub_b import foobar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foobar()
```

If I run the package with `python pypkg` it works just fine. The problem starts when I try to use `foobar` from outside.  I added `pypkg` to the path but when I try to import `foobar` it raises an `ImportError` exception. Here is a demo:

```
In [1]: from pypkg.sub_b import foobar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-37682ecaec63> in <module>()
----> 1 from pypkg.sub_b import foobar

[...]/pypkg/sub_b/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from sub_a import foo
      2 
      3 def foobar():
      4         foo()
      5         print 'bar'

ImportError: No module named sub_a
```

The `ImportError` happens not because it cannot find `sub_b` -- it can -- the problem happens because the package cannot import its own "neighbor subpackage". Which brings us to the question: How to properly import `foobar` from outside?

I made an extensive research on the topic and the vast majority of questions on SO are people that didn't place `__init__.py` files, observe this is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `__main__.py` is seen as a script and not part of the `pypkg` module. And from `__main__.py`s standpoint, `sub_a` and `sub_b` are seen as two modules that don't share a common parent-module. If you changed your layout to

```
pypkg
├── __main__.py
└── pkg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sub_a
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── sub_b
        └── __init__.py
```

`sub_a` and `sub_b` will share the common parent module `pkg`, even when called from `__main__.py`. This allows you to do relative imports in `sub_b/__init__.py`:

```
from ..sub_a import foo
```

Under Python 2 you may need to add the line

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: You will need to update the import in `__main__.py` to  `from pkg.sub_b import foobar`

Comment: Thank you Nils! Is this the regular approach? It feels "hacky" to me. In my point of view, a package should be able to import other components without using relative imports.

Comment: Relative imports exist exactly so that modules can import components from neighbouring modules within one package. You should only use absolute imports if you're importing from other packages.

Answer (score 0):

python calculate the path according to your working path.

So you could choose whether use absolute module path with fixed working path or relative module path with variable working path.

Comment: @tel Honestly I don't remember... this is such an old post.